# Can I wear a red hijab?

Tags: hijab

Am I allowed to wear a red hijab? I am concerned because red is known to be the colour of shaytan. I have talked to a few sheikhs and they each gave me different answers. Please help me I'm a new hijabi and I love the colour red and I really want to know.

Comment: You can wear hijab in any color you like there's no color of shaytan, but some scholars would recommend you to follow local traditions outside of your home if there are any at your location.

Comment: Yes, medi is right. Purpose of hijab should be kept in mind, it is to avoid any attention towards you and making it clear that you are a muslim woman.

Answer (score 2):

Wearing head-covers that are dyed pure red is acceptable for women as pointed out in [this fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/2843):

> Red: It was reported that wearing pure red is forbidden for men, but not for women, because of the hadeeth of Ibn ‘Umar: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) forbade mafdam” (reported by Imaam Ahmad and Ibn Maajah, 3591). Mafdam is something that is filled with red safflower dye. According to the commentary of al-Sindi on Sunan al-Nisaa’i, mafdam is something that is filled with red. It was reported that if ‘Umar saw a man wearing a garment dyed red with safflower, he would pull him aside and say, “Leave this for the women.” (Reported by al-Tabari).

Answer (score 1):

All Praise to Allah Subhanahu wa Taala and blessings of Him be on Prophet Muhammad peace be upon him His family and companions,

There is no prohibition to females for wearing red garments ,prohibition applies to men for wearing red garments which would be dyed with red colour completely.

See also [this](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2013/08/28/can-women-wear-colorful-clothing/).

Allah Swt and His Messenger knows best.

Answer (score 0):

First, Red is not the color of shaitan his color is unknown no one saw him before so yes you can wear a red hijab.